# How to insert data into intermediary table and can this be done in single mysql query?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following tables as of now

Table - mytags

```
| tag_id | tag_name |
|    1   |   home   |
|    2   |   work   |

TABLE - mytasks

| task_id |     task_name     |
|    14   | do my the dishes  |
|    12   | Make presentation |

TABLE - mytasks_mytags

| mytag_id | mytask_id |
|     1    |    14     |
|     2    |    14     |
```

Now everytime a user creates a new tasks , i make a entry into `mytasks` table , What i would like to know is how do i also make an entry into `mytasks_mytags` table ? I am a newbie to mysql , so excuse me being a total noob.  so suppose a use makes a task with the following tags:

> "make presentation and get coffee" (task) - [ "work" , ""home ] 
>   (tags)

As you can see the tasks has 2 tags , how do i go about inserting into the mytasks_mytags table the task_id and also the 2 tags id's ??

So basically everytime a tasks is created i am thinking of running the following steps:

- INSERT task into mytasks table.
- store returned id
- RETRIEVE id's of tags user has selected.
- NOW INSERT into `mytasks_mytags` table the `mytasks.task_id` and also `mytags.tag_id` , now sure how i would go about inserting if there are more then 1 tags... any help ?

If i'am not being clear please let me know. i can break it down further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT can insert into only one table in a given statement. You will have to do at least two statements.

First insert into the mytasks table:

```
INSERT INTO mytasks (task_name) VALUES ('make presentation and get coffee');
```

Then do an `INSERT...SELECT` statement in which the SELECT matches multiple rows, so you can get the respective mytag_id values. Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the value of the mytask_id that you just inserted (I assume it's an auto-incrementing column).

```
INSERT INTO mytasks_mytags (mytag_id, mytask_id)
  SELECT tag_id, LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM mytags
  WHERE tag_name IN ('home','work');
```

The above SELECT fetches the tag_id from each row, and uses the last generated id from the previous INSERT as the second column on each row.

Since you probably want the task and the tags to appear to be a single change in the database, the way to do this is with a *transaction*. As long as you use InnoDB tables, you can make several changes and commit them together. No other request to the database can see the changes in a partially-completed state.

Comment: thanks , this really helped me , btw , since i am using node i had to use `insertId` instead of LAST_INSERT_ID() ... article link here --> http://www.technicalkeeda.com/nodejs-tutorials/nodejs-mysql-retrieve-last-inserted-id